# Генерация звука в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио

Необходимо сгенерировать звуковой файл типа такого:

- секунду звучит писк
- 3 секунды тишина
- 7 секунд пищит.

Частота писка не меняется, меняется только длительность, что-то типа азбуки Морзе.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное в *python*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/audiogen/

Вроде подходящая библиотека.

```
beep_silence = itertools.chain(audiogen.beep(), audiogen.silence(0.5))
infinite_beeps = itertools.cycle(beep_silence) 
audiogen.sampler.write_wav(sys.stdout, infinite_beeps)
```

Answer (score -2):

[ссылка на модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html?highlight=signal) signal- модуль обработчиков для асинхронных событий. Выполняет обработку сигналов в Python.

Comment: Вопрос был про генерацию звука. Модуль signal - вообще не про звук.